# Issue calling another library function using command line argument in Python

Tags: python-2.7, arguments, parameter-passing

I am trying to call different library functions based on the input command-line argument.

My main function would take the input argument and will call the function based on the parameter passed to cli. This is my main function.

```
from lib.updatefeed import *
    def main():
    ......
    ......
    parser.add_argument('-update', type=str, nargs='?', help='Update the local storage')
    if args.update:
        gather(args.update)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Here, gather() is another function in another python library that I have already imported in the main program.

Here is the body of the imported library with gather() function

```
def gather(self):
    if not os.path.exists('intel'):
        os.mkdir('intel')
    print "Starting update process"
    counter = 0
    ioc_list = []
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    for source in IP.iteritems():
        print source
        name = source + timestr
        print name
        file = open(name, 'w')
        c = connect(source,params=url_param())
        for line in c:
            if line.startswith("/") or line.startswith('\n') or line.startswith("#"):
                pass
            else:
                file.write(line+'\n')
```

So my gather() function will be called when the "-update" param is passed to the command line.
The function of gather() function would be to create a directory named "intel".
Then it will iterate through a list of IPs and create file names based on the IP and timestamp. It will then call the connect function to create an HTTP connection to the IP.
It will parse the contents of the IP and write it to the file.

I am not able to achieve this by using my program I have added here. 
For some reason, the call from the main() function itself is not succeeding. 
I tried adding "print" statements in the gather() function to see what parts are working.
Can the community help me on this please.

Comment: Could you please include the line with the import in your code sample?

Comment: At which of the lines you pasted above do you get the error? What is the error message?

Comment: @jhinghaus : Added the import "from lib.updatefeed import *"  where updatefeed.py in the lib that contains the gather() function.

Comment: @barny There is no error in the code I added. It just doesnt call the gather() function when the argument is passed to main.

Comment: What do you get when you print args.update? print it before the line 'if args.update:'

Comment: I won't actually give you a -1 for 'from lib.updatefeed import *' - but importing * is generally regarded as bad style.

Comment: @barny thanks. I imported the specific function, gather(), hasn't helped much.

Comment: Can you print something in front of the call to gather()? 
BTW: You have 8 spaces in front of `gather(args.update)` and 4 spaces in front of `main()`. That is no big problem for python but you should not do this. Use 4 spaces for each level.

Comment: @jhinghaus tried printing a string, but it did not print..looks like some issue with my arg passing.

Comment: Are you actually calling `parser.parse_args()` somewhere? You would need to do that *after* adding the `-update` argument. Please show that part of the code.

Comment: @TomZych here is my main file : https://github.com/abhinavbom/Threat-Intelligence-Hunter/blob/master/tih.py    The last few lines of the code has the call to gather function which is located here : https://github.com/abhinavbom/Threat-Intelligence-Hunter/blob/master/lib/updatefeed.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem lies in the argument characteristics. By Defining     `parser.add_argument('-update', type=str, nargs='?', help='Update the local storage')` I am asuming that One argument will be passed to the command line along with the `-update` param. 
But I only care about the -update arg to be present in the command line without any additional entity. 
This can be overcome by changing the line of script to:

```
parser.add_argument('-update', action='store_true', help='Update the local storage')
```

This will ensure that the presence of only -update will call the function '`gather()`'.